# Footable Pagination is Not Work with Filter in Ng-Repeat

Tags: angularjs, footable

I Used Footable pagination for pagination in ng-repat data. when i used filter in ng-repeat then my pagination is not working.

If i have 10 records with 2 paging and i filter the data which is on 2 page then it display 2 pages and 1 is for blank and 2 for data which is filtered.

### My Table PageSize

`<table class="table m-b-none t-a-m" ui-jq="footable" data-page-size="10">`

### My Ng-Repeat

`<tr ng-repeat="A in B | filter :  {IsActive : status, RegionId  : user.ClientRegion , ClientName : user.CompanyName} | filter : {DriverFirstName:filterText } " id="{{accident.Id}}">`

### My Footable

`<td colspan="8" class="text-right">
        <ul class="pagination hide-if-no-paging"></ul>
 </td>`

so, how can i solved pagination problem ?

Comment: What exactly paginate library are you using?

Comment: hey, i am using footable jquery

Comment: Ok. Can you provide jsfiddle?

Comment: no because it is implemented in current project and do not have sample app for this. but i used ng-repeat with filter. onload of page pagination looks good but when i filter data is breaks.

Comment: Without example of code we can not solve your problem. Sorry.

Comment: i have updated my question with some sample code which i have.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `data-filter="#whatever"` to your table element and input field with `id="whatever"` and removing the `filter` you use to search from your `ng-repeat`.

Remember also to include `footable.filter.js`.

**Search field**

```
<input id="accident-table" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
```

**Table**

```
 <table class="table m-b-none t-a-m" ui-jq="footable" 
      data-filter="#accident-table" data-page-size="10">...</table>
```

**ng-repeat**

```
<tr ng-repeat="A in B | filter :  {IsActive : status, RegionId  : user.ClientRegion , ClientName : user.CompanyName}"
   id="{{accident.Id}}">
```